# ConcurrentHashMap: remove on condition

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, data-structures, thread-safety

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` which used as an in-memory storage (or a cache, you might say)

What I'd like to achieve is: Concurrently check if an item "is ready", and if so, remove it from the map (+ return it to the caller). There's no direct method that enables me to do that.

The only solution I came up with is having an `ItemContainer` which will contain both the item and meta-data (`isReady` field). On every access, I'll have to apply `merge` or `compute` operations. Essentially replacing the container of the object on every access/check.

Questions:

1. Is my solution seem reasonable?
2. Are there any good libraries that achieves something similar?

I added a "boilerplate" code as requested:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Storage storage = new Storage();
        storage.put("1", new Record("s", 100));
        storage.put("2", new Record("s", 4));
        storage.removeIf("1", Main::isReady);
    }

    public static boolean isReady(Record record) {
        return record.i > 42;
    }

    public static class Record {

        public Record(String s, Integer i) {
            this.s = s;
            this.i = i;
        }

        String s;
        Integer i;
    }

    public static class Storage {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Record> storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        public void put(String key, Record record) {
            storage.put(key, record);
        }

        public Record removeIf(String key, Function<Record, Boolean> condition) {
            return null; // TODO: implement
        }
    }
}
```

**Other solutions (with tradeoffs):**

1. Always `remove()` on check and then `merge()` it back to the map.
2. Use a cache with some reasonable policy of items evacuation (i.e. LRU) and check only evacuated items.

**Based on @ernest_k solution:**

```
public Record removeIf(String key, Predicate<Record> condition) {
    AtomicReference<Record> existing = new AtomicReference<>();

    this.storage.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> {
        boolean conditionSatisfied = condition.test(v);

        if (conditionSatisfied) {
            existing.set(v);
            return null;
        } else {
            existing.set(null);
            return v;
        }
    });

    return existing.get();
}
```

Comment: The description doesn't give us the idea that your current code would. Please post the code.

Comment: @ernest_k, I truly believe that the description is detailed enough to answer my question + I don't really have a working code yet. Would you like me to elaborate more on certain things?

Comment: I can prepare some code though

Comment: "Concurrently check if an item *is ready*" - Is the *item* the key or the value of the `Map`? Does the *item* have to be removed from the `Map` as fast as possible after it's *ready*? If not, can you have some task that synchronizes on the entire map, iterates over it, and removes all *items* that are *ready*?

Comment: @JacobG., I'd like so (that the item will be removed as soon as possible without iterating the whole map)

Comment: Another possibility I can accept is that **on every update** of the item the check will be done. So update will either only update or update+remove

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the jcache javadoc, see https://static.javadoc.io/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0/javax/cache/Cache.html - (you can add listeners to caches using registerCacheEntryListener), and eg. Ehcache is a jcache impelmentation

Comment: @Daniele, I will consider that - Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` already gives you the guarantee of atomicity with `computeIfPresent`.

> If the value for the specified key is present, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value. The entire method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this map.

So you can just use that:

```
public Record removeIf(String key, Predicate<Record> condition) {

    AtomicReference<Record> existing = new AtomicReference<>();

    this.storage.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> {
        existing.set(v);
        return condition.test(v) ? null : v;
    });

    return existing.get();
}
```

Note that I used `Predicate<Record>` as it should be preferred to `Function<Record, Boolean>`.

The reason for storing the current value in an `AtomicReference` here is to make sure that the returned value is the same one that the predicate was testedd against (otherwise there might be a race condition).

Comment: ernsest_k, There's a problem in this code - The returned value is *the new* value. So if the condition is true then removeIf will return null actually.

Comment: Ouch... I forgot about that part. Need to think about it

Comment: @yaseco I've edited to save the current value in a temporary variable and return it after `computeIfPresent`.

Comment: Thanks!, though I don't understand exactly why would the *reference* ever change? What's the race condition here?

Comment: 1. I'm using an `AtomicReference` instance instead of a `Record` instance because a local variable referenced in a lambda must be final. 2. If I didn't read the current mapped value in the same block that is run atomically to test the condition, then there would be a chance of returning an incorrect value if multiple threads call the method with the same key...

Comment: I see. By the way, I added your solution to my post with the modification that `null` is returned if the condition is not met and the reference, otherwise. I think it's valid, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `null` is returned in one case: `key` is not already mapped in `storage` (`computeIfAbsent` won't run at all). If `key` is already in `storage`, the current value is returned whether the condition is met or not (this part is easy to change).

Comment: thanks @ernest_k this alternative is genius, but to nitpick something you said: "then there would be a chance of returning an incorrect value if multiple threads call the method with the same key" I thought that in this case not because you are creating a new AtomicReference on each thread access. So even if two removeIf()'s happen to the same key, each thread would have a different version of AtomicReference.

Comment: @Delark You're right that each thread will have its own `existing` object. But that does not make them immune to the potential race condition. If `existing.set(v)` and `condition.test(v)` were called in a non-atomic way (`get` followed by `put`/`replace`), two threads running with the same key could return inconsistent results (because the second thread might run `condition.test(v)` after the first one had changed the mapping in `storage`). `AtomicReference` is a workaround only to modify local variables in the lambda expression, no more.

Comment: You are correct, my wrong assumption (I misread your sentence) was that you were using the AtomicReference holder because of potential race conditions, in reality your argument was that "(not reading)  the current mapped value in the same block" is the culprit of potential race conditions which is an argument I completely agree with, I just though your usage of AtomicReference was to prevent race conditions, in reality is an easier wrapper than initializing a generic array (maybe even less expensive(?)... but I'm not sure) for us to then assign it a result to index 0.

Comment: ... What I think is also valid is the usage of a simple generic holder, and it does not even need to be volatile and synchronized, since the reading is performed in an atomic way (inside the `putIfPresent()`) forcing a delay on the next line (`return existing.get();`) until the transaction is finished... maybe the value should be volatile, but the writing does not need to be synchronized since it (the holder) is subjecting itself to the map's inner lock.
The funny thing is that **Effective Java - item 79** explicitly ...

Comment: ... prohibits the usage of functions inside synchronized bodies, the way `putIfPresent()` does, ... maybe to prevent us from overthinking it...

Comment: @Delark thanks for the remark. I didn't give `AtomicReference` much thought. I suppose there are simpler or more optimal alternatives. If you're sure about one (like a singleton array or other holders), you're surely welcome to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55816232/1504556) which uses an `AtomicReference` is in essence an attempt of a workaround on the "why variables used in lambdas need to be effectively final" problem. It is an ok'ish workaround to this problem, but an `AtomicReference` will have a little bit of overhead. Another option is to use an array reference although I understand that is frowned upon (however, I can't see why it would have unexpected side-effects in this case?)

Alas, here's another one. I think a by-the-book solution would be this:

```
public class MyMapClass<K,V> {        
    private final ConcurrentMap<K,V> storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    public V removeIf(K key, final Predicate<V> condition) {
        BiFunctionForConditionalRemove bf = new BiFunctionForConditionalRemove(condition);
        storage.computeIfPresent(key, bf);
        return bf.existingValue;
    }
        
    private class BiFunctionForConditionalRemove implements BiFunction<K, V, V> {
        private V existingValue;
        private final Predicate<V> condition;

        public BiFunctionForConditionalRemove(Predicate<V> condition) {
            this.condition = condition;
        }

        @Override
        public V apply(K existingKey, V existingValue) {
            this.existingValue = existingValue;
            return condition.test(existingValue) ? null : existingValue;
        }
    }
}
```

This for sure is a lot more verbose, but I would argue it is a bit faster than using a temporary `AtomicReference` for each invocation. (just a wild claim, I haven't measured it). The assumption is that using a throw-away instance of BiFunction for each invocation is faster than using a throw-away AtomicReference for each invocation. In fact I don't think it adds overhead to use a specialized version of BiFunction compared to using a Lambda. Same work for the JVM.

Side note: One thing I don't like with the using-computeIfPresent-trick for doing a conditional remove is that I can't find evidence in the source code for `ConcurrentHashMap` that JDK developers have anticipated this situation, although it will work. If the majority of your use-cases do not hit the condition (meaning no delete) then `ConcurrentHashMap` will still do an (unnecessary) replace operation in the map. It doesn't seem to check if `newVal == oldVal` but blindly proceeds with the operation regardless. This means you'll have locking contention on the map even where it is not needed. I hope I'm wrong on this. If not, there's for sure room for improvement in the JDK8 I've looked into.